# Expanding control sequences and writing the raw result to a file

Tags: write

I'm attempting to automatically generate a BiBTeX file from within LaTeX. I'd like to expand all control sequences, but disable any active character expansion in the output. The idea is that the following pseudo-code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
  \def\macro{ěščř}
  \output{\jobname.output}{\macro žýáíé}
\end{document}
```

should generate a file containing `ěščřžýáíé` in UTF-8.

## Plain TeX

I first arrived at this Plain TeX solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
  \def\macro{ěščř}
  \immediate\newwrite\fd
  \immediate\openout\fd=\jobname.output
  \immediate\write\fd{\macro žýáíé}
  \immediate\closeout\fd
\end{document}
```

This generated a file containing

```
\unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {e\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 20 e\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor \unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {s\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 20 s\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor \unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {c\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 20 c\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor \unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {r\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 20 r\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor \unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {z\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 20 z\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor \unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {y\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 19 y\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor \unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {a\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 19 a\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor \unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {\OT1\i \global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 19 \OT1\i \egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor \unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {e\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 19 e\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor
```

Whoa. Inserting `\input{\jobname.output}` typesets the expected output, so this is clearly an expanded form of the `ěščřžýáíé` string, but not what I wanted.

## The [`newfile`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newfile) LaTeX package

### The `\addtostream` command

The next thing I tried was the `\addtostream` command provided by the [`newfile`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newfile) LaTeX package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newfile}
\begin{document}
  \newoutputstream{out}
  \openoutputfile{\jobname.output}{out}
  \def\macro{ěščř}
  \addtostream{out}{\macro žýáíé}
  \closeoutputstream{out}
\end{document}
```

This generated a file containing

```
\IeC {\v e}\IeC {\v s}\IeC {\v c}\IeC {\v r}\IeC {\v z}\IeC {\'y}\IeC {\'a}\IeC {\'\i }\IeC {\'e}
```

Again, not what I wanted.

### The `writeverbatim` environment

Next I tried the `writeverbatim` environment provided by the package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newfile}
\begin{document}
  \newoutputstream{out}
  \openoutputfile{\jobname.output}{out}
  \begin{writeverbatim}{out}ěščřžýáíé\end{writeverbatim}
  \closeoutputstream{out}
\end{document}
```

This generated a file containing `ěščřžýáíé` in UTF-8, just as I wanted, but I need control sequence expansion. Any ideas?

Comment: Would you be prepared to switch to xelatex or lualatex? They treat UTF8 characters in the same way as `a`,...,`z`, `A`, ..., `Z`.

Comment: Sadly, that's not an option. The package needs to work with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Okay. Perhaps `\@onelevel@sanitize\macro` before writing?

Comment: @Witiko I just replace \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} by \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} in plain solution and everything is good

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: That works ok, but it doesn't work for multiple indirection.

Comment: @touhami: Well, what do you know – removing the `inputenc` package fixed it.

Comment: @Witiko i don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: @touhami: That your solution works just fine. Thank you. :-)

Comment: I did not want to do a last-minute-switch to lualatex, I just post-processed the file using `sed -i "s/\\\\IeC //g" jobname.output`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable interpretation of UTF-8 characters using the same mechanism that's used for interpreting them, that is redefine `\UTF@two@octets` and similar macros to produce the string representation of the following characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\disable@UTF}{%
  \def\UTFviii@two@octets##1##2{\string##1\string##2}%
  \def\UTFviii@three@octets##1##2##3{\string##1\string##2\string##3}%
  \def\UTFviii@four@octets##1##2##3##4{\string##1\string##2\string##3\string##4}%
}
\newwrite\witiko@out
\immediate\openout\witiko@out=\jobname.dat
\newcommand{\witikowrite}[1]{%
  \protected@write\witiko@out{\disable@UTF}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Something for activating \texttt{\string\write}

\witikowrite{\emph{ěščřžýáíé}}

\end{document}
```

This will write in the `.dat` file

```
\emph  {ěščřžýáíé}
```

Depending on what you need, you might want to add other “neutralizing” assignments in the second argument to `\protected@write`.

Comment: Thank you, this works just fine in the general case. However in my case, the simpler solution seems to be the delayed inclusion of the `inputenc` package, as described in @touhami's comment.

Comment: @Witiko Sorry to inform you that not including `inputenc` will lead you to disasters; try printing `ß` and you'll see.

Comment: @Witiko moreover, as this is a package you can not know whether the user will load inputenc or not.

Comment: True, but I'm only delaying its inclusion. This is a class and I'm generating the output file at the beginning of its definition. The `inputenc` package gets loaded afterwards. (edit: Sorry for the confusion, this is a class, not a package)

Comment: Although to ensure robustness (another class with `inputenc` loaded could hypothetically `LoadClass` my class), it's perhaps better to locally reset the `UTFviii` macro definitions, when generating the file. Just in case.

Answer (score 5):

If I use `csplain` or `pdfcsplain` (i.e. plain TeX with a little modification) with the source (in UTF8):

```
\newwrite\fout
\immediate\openout\fout=test.txt
\immediate\write\fout{ěščřžýáíé}
\def\macro{žřů}
\immediate\write\fout{\macro}
\bye
```

then I get the result in the file `test.txt` which reads in UTF8:

```
ěščřžýáíé
žřů
```

Just simple. The effect is here due to `csplain` is the format which activates encTeX extension (an extension for UTF8 encoding for pdfTeX).

Comment: encTeX is neat, but I don't think I will be adding it to the class as a dependancy.

Comment: @Witiko LaTeX uses another principle than encTeX: when 8bit TeX engine (pdftex) and UTF8 input are used then LaTeX user must use [utf8]{inputenc} which activates the UTF8 prefixes. EncTeX needs to be activated when format is generated and LaTeX doesn't activate it. I know several people who activate encTeX in their home-made LaTeX and don't use inputenc. But this never will be official LaTeX and the users must accept that the documents for this home-made LaTeX are not simply interchangeable.

Comment: Afaik, encTeX is a part of the TeXLive distribution, so distributing the class along with a Makefile specifying the necessary `pdflatex` flags should do the trick.

Comment: @Witiko Yes. But still there is a potential space for confusions: users cannot use both: encTeX-ed LaTeX plus `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. And maybe, there are many LaTeX tricks based on inputenc internals.

Comment: And another important and potential problem in LaTeX: encTeX totally avoids the LIRC (LaTeX internal representation of characters). LaTeX uses `inputenc -> LIRC -> fontenc`. On the other hand, encTeX maps UTF8 codes directly to control sequences or 8bit codes of chosen font. If you need to avoid 50 % of LaTeX, OK, use encTeX. But it seems to be better to avoid whole LaTeX and to use plain TeX in such situation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following (taken from one of my [blog posts](http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=3031)), I use it to be able to store also `\\` in external files to generate address files. From what I can see it does work for your characters as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% get a copy of `\protected@write
\let\protected@iwrite\protected@write
% patch the copy to add \immediate
\xpatchcmd{\protected@iwrite}{\write}{\immediate\write}{}{}
\makeatother


\newwrite\tempfile
\newcommand{\Anschrift}{ěščř}
\immediate\openout\tempfile=Anschrift.txt
\makeatletter
\protected@iwrite\tempfile{\let\\\relax}{\Anschrift žýáíé}
\immediate\closeout\tempfile
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\input{Anschrift.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The file will contain `\IeC {\v e}\IeC {\v s}\IeC {\v c}\IeC {\v r}...`

Comment: You are right, this won't work then :-(

Comment: By the way, I seem to have already seen that code for `\protected@iwrite`. `;-)`

Comment: Good memory :-)